# Is there any mid-representation between LLVM IR and source code?

Tags: objective-c, llvm, compiler-optimization

For example,
A line of objective-C code [NSData alloc] will be transformed into a call to objc_msgSend.
Is there any method I can intercept this level's representation with out getting into these LLVM IR mess?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Clang as a front end for Objective C, then you can also work on its Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) which is close to the parsed source code. You can have a look at http://clang.llvm.org/docs/IntroductionToTheClangAST.html to get started.